# Blocking request with query string

Tags: .htaccess, mod-security, cloudflare

I'm an under a DDoS attack though I have cloud flare..

I found out that the attacker is accessing the server using query strings "?a=randomnumber"

I don't use query strings in my website so I need to block any IP that tries to add query string in the request

It would be preferable if this can be set in mod_security or CloudFlare

Thanks in advance

Comment: You might want to see if you can do such filtering within cloudflare.  Filtering it on your own servers with mod_security won't do much good to stem the DDoS.

Answer (score 0):

Is the attacker hitting your IP directly at all?

It is really hard to give additional guidance without knowing your pricing plan (the WAF might also help, if you are on a paid plan).

[Some other tips for dealing with a DDoS](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170196-I-am-under-DDoS-attack-what-do-I-do-)